# rich text editor for vue js with math formula support

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to use a rich text editor in my Vue application, I find CKEditor 4 for Vue with the WIRIS plugin but I couldn't find any guide or installation document for Vue anyone can help me to run WIRIS on CKEditor Vue or introduce any replace editor?

Comment: Try TinyMCE i dont know if it support math fomula but its a good text editor